# How to filter a query according to creation date?

Tags: python, django

I have a query and I want to list the objects that created today.

```
query_emails = Email.objects.values('mail_from').annotate(mail_count=Count('mail_from'), mailts=F('mail_timestamp')).order_by()
```

mail_timestamp is the created day and it should be today, so like

```
.filter(mail_timestamp=today)
```

The output of the mail_timestamp is

`'mailts': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 8, 8, 9, 35, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

I used `today = datetime.now()` but it didn't work.

How can I filter this type date?

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date
date.today()
```

this should work

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

`today` means that mail date have to be lower than tomorrow's 00:00:00 and bigger than yesterday's 23:59:59:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

from_date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(1)).replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
to_date = (datetime.now() + timedelta(1)).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)

# if mail_timestamp field type is Datetime:
Email.objects.filter(mail_timestamp__lt=to_date).filter(mail_timestamp__gt=from_date)

# if mail_timestamp field type is timestamp (integer representation):
Email.objects.filter(mail_timestamp__lt=datetime.timestamp(to_date)).filter(mail_timestamp__gt=datetime.timestamp(from_date))
```